# EAccessViolation error when loading or switching desktops

Tags: delphi-10.3-rio, delphi-10.4-sydney

I upgraded from 10.3 (Rio) to 10.4 (Sydney) (with side-by-side installs), now having IDE docking exception, e.g.

Loading the desktop from "C:\Users\gary.walker\AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\BDS\21.0\Default Layout.dst" for doc host windows "DockSite3" failed with message:

"EAccessViolation: Access violation at address 50165CBF in module 'rtl270.bpl'. Read of address 33DEEBFF"

Deleting all .dst files has resolved the issue in at least one case (a coworker).

Also, when attempting to debug a program, I was having a hard failure during debug startup that prevented debugger use, before application began execution. I resolved this problem by copying my Default desktop to my debug desktop.

Another friend had pretty much the same issue and was able to fix it, unfortunately he does not know how he fixed it.

**Question is does anyone know how to fix this?**

I am still waiting for an answer from Embarcadero and this is causing us real problems at the moment.

Comment: What is the question exactly? If you report an issue, then you should write a report at https://quality.embarcadero.com

Answer (score 2):

**I received an answer from Embarcadero support.**

It fixed the problem for me until I adjusted my desktops to the way I wanted them and them - still better than nothing. I suspect there is no solid work-around at this point in time. But, this may work well as long as you are not frequently changing your desktop layouts.

---

There were display layout changes introduced in 10.4.1 that cause the errors that you are seeing.

1. Shut the IDE down
2. In Windows Explorer navigate to: %AppData%\Embarcadero\BDS\21.0
3. Delete the *.dst files at that location (you can back them up first if desired)
4. In Windows Explorer navigate to the product's \bin directory. The default location is: 4. C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin
5. Copy the three default *.dst files from this location to the location in step 2
6. Start the IDE as normal